# why the atom always runs in the same pathway?Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Tags: flask, atom-editor

`Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`

How to change this path "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to atom text editor at all, it is the flask server.
127.0.0.1 is the localhost which you cannot change.
5000 is the port number which can be changed, for which you have to provide port argument to run method

```
app.run(port=5005)
```

Comment: each time i run the multiple codes in flask, i cant open in the browser the new one only the old one is being executed